# How to expand data on angularjs filtering from input field automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have the following:

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="repeatPeople">
<br>
<p>
<input type="text" id="search" ng-model="searchPeople" 
 placeholder="Search" >
</p><br><br>
      <table border="0">
        <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 30px;"></td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
          </tr>  
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat-start="person in people | filter:searchPeople">
            <td>
              <button ng-if="person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = false">-</button>
              <button ng-if="!person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = true">+</button>
            </td>
            <td>{{person.name}}</td>
            <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-if="person.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td colspan="3">{{person.details}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function repeatPeople($scope) {
  $scope.people = [
    {name: "John", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am John and age is 25. I do dance well."},
    {name: "Mary", gender: "Female", details: "Hi ! I am Mary and age is 30. I read books."},
    {name: "Dan", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am Dan and age is 20. I like to play cricket."},
    {name: "Alex", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am Alex and age is 35. I like to watch movies."},
    {name: "Rosy", gender: "Female", details: "Hi ! I am Rosy and age is 25. I play Guitar."}
  ];
}
```

I can able to `search` or `filter` the names and can see their details from the above code on clicking of their icons, but I am facing one issue like: How can I expand the respective icons and it's data automatically on `searching` or `filtering` the respective names to see their details instead of clicking their icon from the input field. Please help me in this regard and Thanks in advance !

Created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/2x3x87kj/).

Answer (score 1):

Try like to this

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="person in result = (people | filter:searchPeople)"> 
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-if="result.length > 0 && searchPeople" ng-repeat-end="">
    <td colspan="3">{{person.details}}</td>
</tr>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hg3anuyq/)

Comment: I have one query that, on executing the above updated answer, if I click on "+" icon, that data is not expanding ? May I know please why ? What to do for expanding and collapsing that ?